# How do you set Kuwait/Riyadh as default time in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

How can i set my default time to Kuwait Riyadh

This is my code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Kuwait/Riyadh');
$date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Is this not working? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The timezones you are looking for are `Asia/Kuwait` and `Asia/Riyadh`. Riyadh is in Saudi Arabia, not Kuwait, so the timezones for the two locations could well be different.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `Kuwait/Riyadh` timezome. There is only `Asia/Kuwait` timezone as in PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php

Answer (score 3):

**The time zones for Kuwait**

```
 date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuwait");
 $time  = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
```

**The time zones for Riyadh**

```
 date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Riyadh");
 $time  = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
```

Both the time zone gives you the same result so you can use any one of above